# Cordova Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: file, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am using cordova with Visual Studio 2015.
My code is working with ripple correctly. But, it is not working with my phone(debug mode). I get this Error message.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///android_asset/veriler/icerik2.json (Error)
```

I think it should be

```
file:///android_asset/www/veriler/icerik2.json
```

I cant solve this problem. How can i do for reach this json file.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Do you load your resource by using a starting slashes like "/library/....." or without it like "library/...."?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file?

Comment: Maybe your icerik2.json isn't being copied to your device. [Chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) might help to verify this. Anyway it would be interesting to know where your icerik2.json is located, so one can reproduce the error.

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced this problem before, It has something todo with the way .wet handles mime types. The simple solution is to rename your .json files to .js.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced some problems trying to load JSON files on a cordova project in Visual Studio. I fixed it changing cordova C# source files, but after sometime I realized that we can just load the JSON file as a TXT file and no problem occurs. Hope the following helps:

**1 -** Try to rename your file from **JSON to TXT.**

**2-** I do not know how you are trying to load it, but I think that you do **something like this** in Javascript Cordova:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    url: 'myfile/myJSONfile.txt',
    success: function (data) {
        var yourJSON = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

**3 -** As you see, you can parse your TEXT file into JSON, **as long as it is a valid JSON.** You could check it at:
Validate JSON

Hope it helps. Best regards!